# How to construct a user(/input)-specified number of objects

Tags: java, class, object

I'm currently doing an intro level undergrad CS course (learning basics of 'program'&'class' building using Java).

The relevant part of my personal (&job related) project: I have a list of zip codes associated with One county.

I'm gonna define a class called 'County'. Then I'm gonna use this class to construct an object of type County, called 'middlesex'.

ie: County middlesex = new County();

Now, in this object, I want to construct a number of objects of class-type ZipCode.

ie: ZipCode objName = new ZipCode();

(Each such ZipCode object is gonna contain certain instance data).

My problem is this. Assume that I don't know how many zipcodes are contained in the Middlesex county. However, I have a .txt file that contains just a list of all the zipcodes of Middlesex county.

Let's say there are n number of zipcodes in this list.

In the object 'middlesex', of class-type 'County', I want to set up a loop. This loop will scan each zipcode in the list, then construct an object of class-type ZipCode for each zipcode.

Thus the loop may go thru n iterations, and construct n objects of type ZipCode.

Thus, for every iteration of the loop, a unique object-reference-name must be created (corresponding to the particular zipcode in the list).

Part of this problem (but distinct and optional), is that I want to know how (if possible), I can set up a structure that allows an inputted (scanned) string to be used as the name of an object-reference.

I apologize if I've made incorrect terminology use. I know that many are gonna suggest arrays. I haven't learned about them yet, but I gotta read about them over this weekend for school. I'm just gonna try to figure this out for a day or two, and then just move on to using arrays to perform this task.

So, if I've made any sense to anyone, is what I'm trying to do possible without arrays?

Thank u.

Comment: It sounds like something that is easily fixed by creating proper classes and collections. Also, I think that you're putting far too much importance to something that doesn't really exist, the "object name". What is an object's "name"? An object has a type -- it's class, and properties -- fields, and those fields can contain Strings. Do you mean variable names? Because if so, then jump off that bandwagon and onto the *reference* wagon.

Comment: So, briefly give your County class a `List<ZipCode>` field, one initialized with `new ArrayList<>()`. And then fill the list when you read the file -- done.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried to make sure that I didn't use the term 'object name'. I think I typed 'object reference name'. Maybe that's just redundant haha, and I should just call it 'object reference'. But yes I understand that there the 'object reference' refers to a 32-bit memory location that stores the memory address of whatever instance data there ought to be in the object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm still not at all clear what you're stuck on, and why simply creating a List field wouldn't work in this situation. This problem doesn't look to require any fancy design patterns, just simple bare-bones Java.

Comment: Oh, so I basically must use the ArrayList<> class? Is List<> class a distinct class aswell?

Comment: If you're not familiar with Lists and ArrayLists, then run don't walk to a tutorial on them. A List is an interface that abstracts the behaviors of several different types of list structures, and an ArrayList is a concrete class that implements the List interface, using an array as its data nucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a very basic scenario, one where one object contains (possibly) many references to objects of a 2nd type, what we call a constructor called "composition" where the relationship here is a "has-a" relationship, County has-a (or has-many) zip codes

As opposed to using inheritance to wrongly try to solve this, the "inheritance" relationship or the "is-a" relationship -- County is not a zip code and zip code is not a county.

The code to create this can be very simple, something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class County {
    private String name;
    private List<String> zipCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor that takes county name
    public County(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addZipCode(String code) {
        zipCodes.add(code);
    }

    // ..... more code
```

If a zip code is a single String, then no need to create a new class for this. If however it is more complex and holds more data than a single String, then create a class for ZipCode, and change the code above to something like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class County {
    private String name;
    private List<ZipCode> zipCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor that takes county name
    public County(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addZipCode(ZipCode code) {
        zipCodes.add(code);
    }

    // getters, setters, a decent toString method override...
```

Where ZipCode could contain....

```
public class ZipCode {
    String code;
    // other fields if needed....

    public ZipCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    // ....
```

then when reading in data, create your County objects and as each Zip code is read in, add it to the appropriate County object using the `addZipCode(...)` method.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. What you've said and your code examples make complete sense to me. Seems like I really need to understand ArrayList<> for this. Unfortunately, I barely have an idea of what 'inheritance' means.-----------------------------------but yes, ZipCode will be a class for slightly compex objects containing multiple instance data values (Fair Market Rent values for different kinds of real estate properties.)----------------------I'm currently just gonna read about ArrayList<> and practice simpe tasks. Thanks for the Example!!!

Answer (score 0):

zipCode is an object of Type ZipCode then what are its fields? Think of the reasons for making it an object and not a variable

"Thus the loop may go thru n iterations, and construct n objects of type ZipCode"
Unforutnality this is not possible without making the use of Arrays 
"structure that allows an inputted (scanned) string to be used as the name of an object"
Nope can do that.

Comment: $$Damn, I really don't know how to use this website properly (I'm just gonna copy-paste from notepad).$$

$$@user10531724; just to confirm, you mean "Nope(,) can(')t do that." right? Also, thanks for your help. Ill run to arrays immediately$$

$$@Hovercraft Full Of Eels; Thanks for your help, I looking at ArrayList<> and List<> info rn.$$

Comment: @fusedReCon Yes You need to use ArrayList or List

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to use ArrayList or List" -- please be specific as you're answering a newbie. You can't just use List out of the box, so this comment on its face value is wrong.